# How to connect two workflows that are on different SharePoint sites?

Tags: workflow, infopath-data-connections

Not being an expert of SharePoint at all, I would like to understand the complexity of connecting two workflows that are located in different SharePoint sites.
In essence, what we would like to do is to initiate a workflow in another site, giving this workflow some information (6 or 7 fields) that come from the **initiator** workflow.

Which are the solutions you have in mind?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible via Workflow. One option is to use an EventReceiver which will get triggered by Workflow1 and let the EventReceiver starts Workflow2.

Comment: Thanks Amal, I think your suggestion makes sense. In terms of man/days, what would you expect to build this?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB, this is not possible Because you cannot cross the site collections. This is true for the SharePoint designer.

But their is one 3rd party option i saw from Bamboo. [Announcing Workflow Conductor 1.5](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2010/10/04/announcing-workflow-conductor-1-5.aspx)